# use the content of local json in a webapp in vue cli 4.2.3

Tags: json, vue.js

I am basically trying to use the json file to store few data and use them in the components.

```
[
  {
    "heroTitle": [
      "Banner image",
      "assets/images/banner/sunset.jpg",
      "sunset.jpg"
    ],
  }
]
```

above is a sample json
below is my component

```
<template>
  <header>
    <div class="hero">
      <h1 class="hero__title">"banner name here"</h1>
      <img src="image path and file here" alt="alt text here" />
    </div>
  </header>
</template>
```

Also, is there a way to edit the jason from the app itself?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can utilize local JSON data in your Vue components.
Assuming you have this JSON data in data object of Vue component, then you can utilize Vue template syntax (tick syntax) such as "this.heroTitle[0]", which refers to "Banner Image".

Comment: I am Kinda new to vue can you help with the syntax and import method, I search the web but failed to understand.